# Aggregate data frame by sequence of events per day

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) like this:

```
 TIMESTAMP               STATUS
 2016-01-01 00:00:00      OFF
 2016-01-01 01:00:00      ON
 2016-01-01 02:00:00      ON
 2016-01-01 03:00:00      OFF
 2016-01-02 00:00:00      ON
 2016-01-02 01:00:00      OFF
 ...
```

I need to aggregate(?) the sequence of statuses for each day. For example the first day in df gives the sequence OFF-ON-ON-OFF whereas the second day just gives OFF-ON

So I need an aggregated data frame by date like this:

```
DAY           SEQUENCE 
2016-01-01    OFF-ON-ON-OFF
2016-01-02    ON-OFF
...
```

Comment: It's not really hard if you divide the problem into steps: 1. sort by day and time 2. create a day column from time (tip: package `lubridate`) 3. concatenate STATUS for each day(a simple for loop for each day, there is not much to vectorize here).

Comment: @dracodoc Nothing in your comments gives any hint at how to aggregate the text strings, which is the question. These comments are not constructive and should be deleted.

Comment: @Hack-R, I added tip for each step. A simple for loop is easy to design and implement, and not necessarily slow. I just wish OP can learn more by himself instead of getting a solution for not so hard specific question.

Comment: @dracodoc No, you did not add any tip for the heart of the question. I know that you are new to StackOverflow and you don't have much experience here, but the types of comments you left, especially the 2nd one are not what our comments are for.

Comment: OK I deleted that 2nd one. I'm not sure if there is "heart" of the question though. I've been reading SO for some years, but just start to find some elements more recently.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(TIMESTAMP) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(TIMESTAMP)) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(sequence = paste(status, collapse = "-"))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  TIMESTAMP = c("2016-01-01 00:00:00", "2016-01-01 01:00:00", "2016-01-01 02:00:00", "2016-01-01 03:00:00", "2016-01-02 00:00:00", "2016-01-02 01:00:00"),
  status = c("OFF", "ON", "ON", "OFF", "ON", "OFF")
)
```

Comment: It's a probably a good idea to sort the time first, just to make sure the event is in right order.

Answer (score 1):

By tradition I'll add a `data.table` solution here:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

s <- "TIMESTAMP, STATUS
2016-01-01 00:00:00, OFF
2016-01-01 01:00:00, ON
2016-01-01 02:00:00, ON
2016-01-01 03:00:00, OFF
2016-01-02 00:00:00, ON
2016-01-02 01:00:00, OFF"

dt <- fread(s)
dt[, day_time := ymd_hms(TIMESTAMP)]
# better to make sure the events is in right order
setorder(dt, day_time)
dt[, DAY := date(day_time)]
dt[, paste0(STATUS, collapse = "-"), by = DAY]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired result, I assume that you want to remove the time stamps as well.  If that is the case, you can use aggregate, as.Date, and paste from base R.

```
df <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP = 
    c('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-01 01:00:00',
      '2016-01-01 02:00:00','2016-01-01 03:00:00',
      '2016-01-02 00:00:00','2016-01-02 01:00:00'), 
  STATUS = c('OFF','ON','ON','OFF','ON','OFF'))

aggregate(df$STATUS, list(as.Date(df$TIMESTAMP)), paste, collapse="-")
## Group.1             x
## 2016-01-01 OFF-ON-ON-OFF
## 2016-01-02        ON-OFF
```

Comment: I believe complex one-liner is generally harder to write, understand, debug and maintain. Also rely on substr to pick up date part could be of problem for not so clean data. The dplyr solution by @DMC is much easier to understand in concept. I still need to use `data.table` because of its performance, though I appreciate the syntax of dplyr.

Comment: While I am huge proponent of dplyr and data.table, the upside of using `aggregate` is that it does not require the person asking the question to unnecessarily install or load a package they may not need or want.  I have adjusted my answer to use as.Date() instead though.  Good call out.

Comment: I agree it's a good reason to just use base R sometimes. The point I wanted to make was not about using whick package, since base R, dplyr, data.table all have their own merits and are valid solutions. At least from my experiences, the usages of R are often a developing process in interactive exploration. I often need to adjust my previous operations or add more based on new developments. So it will be easier to build and update the data frame along my analysis, because the real problem is often not a specific well defined question can be solved in one step.